# why there is a warning with a lexical variable

Tags: common-lisp, lexical-scope

I'm using the [sketch](https://github.com/vydd/sketch) library on this function:

```
(defun init-plot (&optional (title "Plot Window")
                    (x-size 250) (y-size 250))
  (defsketch window ((width x-size)(height y-size)(title title)))
  (make-instance 'window ))
```

Basically is a three optional arguments function, that make a class sketch a create a instance. the function works but it has this warning:

> ;   In INIT-PLOT: Unused lexical variable TITLE

with this, the title option doesn't work, but this variables are on different scopes, so I do not get why I have to change the name of the first variable. because whithout changing it does not work

defscket is a macro that wraps defclass

```
(defmacro defsketch (sketch-name bindings &body body)
                       ...
```

So I don't get the point what is happening here

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sketch, but presumably the `DEFSKETCH` should be on the top-level, and the arguments passed to the `MAKE-INSTANCE` instead.

Comment: This doesn't seem how it is planned or in the sketch tutorial on github

Comment: Perhaps macroexpanding `defsketch` can help you see how `title` is used?

Comment: Looking over the tutorial, it seems to me like all the examples have `DEFSKETCH` as a top-level form. It also seems like giving the window size and title to `MAKE-INSTANCE` works with the examples: `(make-instance 'sketch-examples:hello-world :title "foo" :width 800 :height 300)`

Comment: By convention anything with DEF at front is a top-level form. The DEFSKETCH implementation itself also does violates this, it seems.

Comment: It seems ;-) that you are right @jkiiski. Sorry for the incovenience, I will change the definition using that.

Comment: Thanks @RainerJoswig for that apreciation